# Php delete images from mysql table without showing ID to frontend

Tags: php, mysql

My Database tables:

posts:

| ID | post_title | etc....... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | Title | more |

images:

| ID | post_id | img_url |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | uploads/61d878f77397a4.61355537.jpg |

My current method of deleting images:

```
<?php 
$stmt_images = $conn_posts->prepare("SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `post_id` = ?");
$stmt_images->bind_param("i", $row['ID']);
$stmt_images->execute();
$stmt_images_results = $stmt_images->get_result(); // get result
while($row_image = $stmt_images_results->fetch_assoc()){
echo '<img src="'.$row_image['img_url'].'">';
echo '<button id="delete_button" type="button" data-id="'.$row_image["ID"].'">Delete</button>';
}
?>
```

Ajax:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#delete_button').on('click', function() {
            var deleteId = $(this).data('id');
            var x = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
            if(x){
                $.ajax({
                url: "inc/ajax/delete_images.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                iid: deleteId,
                },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result){
                        $("#info").html(result);
                    }
                }); 
            }
        });
        });
    </script>
```

Then in `inc/ajax/delete_images.php`:
I run a simple delete query based on the iid, "iid = ID of the image row"

Now a frontend user can change that data-id I am blocking that by checking in `delete_images.php` that only the owner of the post can delete the images related to the post that was submitted but i thought of checking some websites and i see OLX does not have any id or hidden input or data variables how can I delete and images without displaying ids frontend as i dont like using data-id

I know I am doing backend checking but i want to make it even more secure by not showing the images ID

OLX Code image:
[image]

Comment: I don't see how you can avoid it. How else is the client supposed to indicate which image the user selected to delete?

Comment: You do need to have some identifier for the image to be able to know which image to delete. You could either pass the image name or generate a random token for each image that you can use instead. But as long as you check that the user owns the image, I don't see an issue with using the ID. The worst that can happen is that a user deletes their own images if they manipulate the id.

Comment: @Barmar that's exactly what i am thinking as i have been coding for about 1-2 yrs now and i can't find a way of doing it but like i said if you check OLX i can't find any ids or indicators for the images

Comment: I don't know what OLX is.

Comment: @Barmar its a famous marketplace like ebay etc....

Comment: Can you provide a URL that shows images with the delete option and no ID?

Comment: @M.Eriksson okay then my current system is the most reliable thanks i just wanted to check if maybe there is a way.  have a good day/night :)

Comment: Plenty of ways you can implement this such as store a hash of data in each row, pass the hash, or guid around, if user changes the hash chances are it won't be a valid one, etc

Comment: @Barmar sure just wait 1min let me take a screenshot

Comment: @Barmar Please check the post i added the screenshot of olx code

Comment: @Barmar If you want to test it you will have to create an account with olx

Comment: Just guessing, but `class="_1cS9Q"` could be used to look up the image.

Comment: That screenshot doesn't say that much, but I do see an image URL in the style. It can also be any of the class names that might be unique. If you delete an image from there, check the network tab and see what data it actually sends to the server instead. I bet there are some identifier in that request. It might pick the ID/filename from some other source. The a-tag you posted doesn't even contain a URL.

Comment: You need to check the JavaScript that's executed when you click on the image, to see how it sends the ID to the server.

Comment: @M.Eriksson nothing goes via the network so my guess is it is not actully changing anything via the server so i am going to check if i can find anything. maybe they are not uploading the images yet and they are only working on the frontend

Comment: If it's on an upload page, before you actually confirm the upload, then yes, that would be a completely different situation that's very different from yours.

Comment: @M.Eriksson ya i see sorry becuse some websites use ajax to upload then they show the image id and i thought maybe olx works the same but i can't confirm becuse my current olx account is very much fake and olx wont let me post cuz i cant confirm my ph number or email lol but i think olx propably works the same why i built it.

Comment: @M.Eriksson thanks for the help in confirming my initial thought :D